# Why does using $in query return different result than $or with equality checks with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When running some queries against our database we ran into some strange results:

```
db.transactions.count({$or: [{action: 'sell', action: 'buy'}]})
```

returned 241485

```
db.transactions.count({$and:[{dateTime: {$gt: startDateTime}},
                             {$or: [{action: 'sell'}, {action: 'buy'}]}]})
```

returned 320487

in other words adding the $and clause, ended up with more results than without. 
We couldn't make sense of this until we looked at the documentation and it says:

> $or versus $in
>
> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or operator.

We then converted the $or query into a $in query

```
db.transactions.count({action: {$in:['sell','buy']}})
```

and this return 527475 which is a result that made sense (we also counted sell and buy separately)

We are wondering why this is the case, and is this a rule than when dealing with equality checks for the value of the same field we **should always** use the $in operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query is incorrect. You are breaking a basic "hash/map" rule here by defining the same key twice:

```js
db.transactions.count({$or: [{action: 'sell', action: 'buy'}]})
```

So this is only considering `action: 'buy'` as this overwrites the previous key. The same as this:

```js
db.transactions.count({$or: [{ action: 'buy'}]})
```

It should be this, like you did the second time around:

```js
db.transactions.count({$or: [{action: 'sell' } , { action: 'buy'}]})
```

And without other conditions as you did, and therefore equivalent to the shortened version with [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```js
db.transactions.count({ "action": { "$in": [ 'sell','buy' ] } })
```

So there was the initial problem, compounded by all of your statements not being the same.

Comment: you are of course correct, coding blindness strikes again (still curious about why mongo prefers the $in vs $or query)

Comment: @machunter It's not really a matter of "prefer" ( with the possible exception of index selection ) but just that it's "less noise". $in basically is an $or operation, just in shorthand form rather than specifying the same field over and over.